# Event driven language for Robotics

Tags: programming-languages, artificial-intelligence, robotics

There are several options that are available like C, C++, Matlab and some more. But is there a language that naturally feels like Event programming?

For example: If I see a red ball (Event) ---> Do this (Action)

Comment: These are modelled with a state machine generally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET Micro Framework can be an option for you. It has very little run-time, about 300Kb. You can program your MCU (ARM[7/9/CMx..]) with VB or C# using Visual Studio. While talking about robotics, hardware interrupts are also important. There is an option to use native code RPL, but I'm not sure it's possible to implement hardware interrupts like timer and edge triggering.. There are events for them, but they may do pooling behind the scenes.. Which means it's not real-time.
And MS Robotic Studio is a free tool that also serves event driven programming, and even Visual Programming (diagram based like Simulink).